# Can't find the error in following code :- expected unqualified-id before try()

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void try(char s[])
{
    if(strlen(s)>5)
    {
        puts("Error\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    char string[10];
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--)
    {
        scanf("%s",&string);
        try(string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Still can't find the error... try is a simple function and as always i am creating a func and calling it. compiler is giving error - (expected unqualified-id before 'try')

Comment: Your line `scanf("%s",&string);` is wrong - you are passing a pointer to a pointer. Should be no `&`. Is not the problem your compiler complains about though...

Comment: @Floris Thats's not the problem scanf allows addres-of pointer to  a char array. it's not a pointer

Comment: Well my compiler says `17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’` and that's without all warnings turned on (using C compiler)

Comment: @Floris I am compiling my code with g++ -o o test.cpp

Comment: That explains. You tagged your code with "C", and it looks like C, but you are compiling with C++ compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to compile your code as C++ rather than C. In C++, `try` is a [reserved word](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) (it is used in exception handling).

```
$ gcc test.c
$ g++ test.c
test.c:3:6: error: expected unqualified-id before 'try'
```

You can use `-x` to set the language explicitly (with either `gcc` or `g++`):

```
$ gcc -x c test.c
$ gcc -x c++ test.c
test.c:3:6: error: expected unqualified-id before 'try'
```

Comment: Thanks... Oh man  I could have thought of any function name . why TRY

Comment: I would also use a name other than string for your string!

Comment: @Steve Why? You can easily have `string string` in your code.

Comment: a) `include <string.h>` and a variable called `string` is confusing, b) it is not truly a string as such.

Comment: Actually, @RamanSingh, `TRY` would have been OK. Your problem was that you used `try`… :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-x c` to your invocation or renaming your file to `main.c`. It could be that `gcc` is choosing to compile your C file as C++ for some reason.